# Could not infer generic parameter when calling protocol static method

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, xcode10

Using a Playground and given these definitions:

```
import Foundation

protocol MoneyTrakObject {
    var key: String { get set }

    init()
}

extension MoneyTrakObject {
    static func objectFromDB<T: MoneyTrakObject>(for key: String, queue: DispatchQueue? = nil, completion: @escaping (T) -> Void) -> String? {
            // after data is retrieved, call completion closure
            let valueObject = T()
            completion(valueObject)

        return "dbToken"
    }
}


protocol Transaction: MoneyTrakObject {
    var amount: Int { get set }
}


struct BasicTransaction: Transaction {
    var key = UUID().uuidString
    var amount = 0

    init() {}
}

struct RecurringTransaction: Transaction {
    var key = UUID().uuidString
    var amount = 0

    init() {}
}
```

I would expect that I could do this:

```
let token1 = BasicTransaction.objectFromDB(for: "") { (transaction) in
    // use transaction
}

let token2 = RecurringTransaction.objectFromDB(for: "") { (transaction) in
    // use transaction
}
```

However I get the `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred` error when calling the static method and I'm not sure why.

Comment: try declaring the resulting type explicitly

Comment: @LeoDabus In the closure? token1 and token2 are strings. The closure is what's returning the explicit type.

Comment: You can add another parameter to pass the expected type

Comment: I mean inside your closure not the tokens

Comment: If you can provide an answer that works, then I can accept it. Adding the type in the closure does work. so now it says (transaction: BasicTransaction) in ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see why you need the generic constraint. If you change the extension of your protocol to this:

```
extension MoneyTrakObject {
    static func objectFromDB(for key: String, queue: DispatchQueue? = nil, completion: @escaping (Self) -> Void) -> String? {
        // after data is retrieved, call completion closure
        let valueObject = Self()
        completion(valueObject)

        return "dbToken"
    }
}
```

Your code compiles just fine. `Self` is a placeholder for the actually implementing type.

Answer (score 1):

Well... the only place where `T` is used is inside the completion handler argument. When you write this:

```
let token1 = BasicTransaction.objectFromDB(for: "") { (transaction) in
    // use transaction
}
```

The compiler has no idea what type `transaction` is and hence cannot specialize the generic function. Provide some type info like this:

```
let token1 = BasicTransaction.objectFromDB(for: "") { (transaction: Transaction) in
    // use transaction
}

let token2 = BasicTransaction.objectFromDB(for: "") { (transaction: BasicTransaction) in
    // use transaction
}
```

Comment: BasicTransaction and RecurringTransaction are the types, but I get the idea.